# How to disable the date (tomorrow date) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to disable the next date. I can select the previous date but not the next coming dates. Can any one help me? This is the code I am using.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
          $(function() {
              $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
          });
      </script>

    </head>
     <body>
       <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can disable selectability of future dates by specifying `0` for the `maxDate` option.

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: 0 // 1 for tomorrow, 2 for day-after, and so on..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd',maxDate: 0 });
```

Comment: While iam trying to insert into database it is redirecting to the same page if i add date.I need to insert date also.

Comment: can you show the sql query and the ajax which u are using..?@user3818933

Comment: It is already on top of the page which i used js files and the text.

Comment: function add()
 {
  $data=array(
  
  'rec_date'=>$this->input->post('rec_date'),                               );
  $this->db->insert('tablename',$data);

 }    This the sql code